# Is casting to `any()` a good solution for having Dialyzer accept ETS match patterns?

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

Is casting to `any()` a good solution for having Dialyzer accept ETS match patterns?

Dialyzer and match specifications don't play well together, and there doesn't seem to be a standard solution:

- http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2012-June/067581.html
- https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-892

Here's a complete example of the solution I'm considering. If `matcher('_')` on the last line is changed to '_' then Dialyzer complains about a bad record construction, but with the `matcher/1` function all seems to be well:

```erl
-module(sample).
-record(rec, {field :: number}).
-export([main/1]).

-type matchvar() :: '$1' | '$2' | '$3' | '$4' | '$5' | '$6' | '$7' | '$8' | '$9' | '$10' | '$11' | '$12' | '$13' | '$14' | '$15' | '$16' | '$17' | '$18' | '$19' | '$20' | '$21' | '$22'.


-spec matcher('_' | matchvar()) -> any().
matcher(X) ->
    case node() of
        '$ will never match' -> binary_to_term(<<>>);
        _ -> X
    end.


main(_Args) ->
    ets:match('my_table', #rec{field = matcher('$1')}, 1).
```

This works because Dialyzer can't tell statically that the unreachable first clause of `matcher/1` is unreachable. Since `binary_to_term/1` returns `any()`, Dialyzer infers the return type of `matcher/1` to be `any()`.

Is this trick a good way of keeping Dialyzer happy when working with match specs? By "good," I mean:

- low runtime cost
- few footguns
- there isn't a better (safer, faster, more ergonomic) way

I peeked at the implementation of `node()` and think it's just a pointer dereference, so cost should be low. And '$ will never match' will really never match because `node()` [always returns an atom with an `@` in it](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/distributed.html). But there must be a better way.

There are really two questions here, that I've combined to avoid the [X Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/309053):

1. Is the technique above a good way to get Dialyzer to treat something as `any()`?
2. Is getting Dialyzer treat `matcher('_')` as `any()` a good solution for working with match specifications?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this is a good solution because you're doing useless work (however small) to satisfy something at compile time, and you're tricking dialyzer by doing so.

When this situation arises, I usually extend the record to include the match variables and live with it (usually my records are `-opaque` so the fields types are controlled in the constructor).

You can always export only a subtype of the actual type instead of using `-opaque` (elaborating on [Pierre Krafft's comment from ERL-892](https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-892?focusedCommentId=14491)):

```
-module(sample).

-record(rec, {field :: number() | '_'}).
-type rec() :: #rec{field :: number()}.
-export_type([rec/0]).

-export([main/1]).

-spec main(rec()) -> {[[rec()]], ets:continuation()} | '$end_of_table'.
main(Rec) ->
    ets:match('my_table', Rec#rec{field = '_'}, 1).
```

```erlang
-module(sample_user).

-export([main_ok/0, main_error/0]).
main_ok() ->
    sample:main({rec, 1}).

main_error() ->
    sample:main({rec, '_'}).
```

```sh
sample_user.erl
   7: Function main_error/0 has no local return
   8: The call sample:main({'rec', '_'}) breaks the contract (rec()) -> {[[rec()]],ets:continuation()} | '$end_of_table'
```

Comment: Re "doing useless work (however small) to satisfy something at compile time" – do you know if anyone has proposed zero-cost casting for Dialyzer?

Comment: @MaxHeiber I'm not sure I understand the question: Dialyzer works on types, so its cost in runtime is 0. Maybe you mean something like ```-compile({inline,[build_match/1]}).
-spec build_match(rec()) -> #rec{}.
build_match(Rec) ->
    Rec#rec{field = '_'}.
```?

Comment: I'd forgotten about `inline`, that's nice! I was thinking about something like Flow's type casting assertions (https://flow.org/en/docs/types/casting/) mypy's casts https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/casts.html or TypeScript `as` type assertions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types.

Comment: @MaxHeiber I haven't seen that in Dialyzer, I think that to be able to freely cast any type you need to suppress the warnings or trick dialyzer the way you did in your example

Comment: I'm trying to recommend best practices for using Dialyzer in a large codebase and unfortunately I don't think devs would go for this solution. It's just too much code to maintain, especially for large records: the type alias has to duplicate information about each field.